# Magento 2.4.3 Invalid block type: Magento\Backend\Block\Order\Create\Form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I upgraded the Magento Version 2.4.3, in the Admin Sales-Create New Order, I am getting the error of

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Backend\Block\Order\Create\Form
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Backend\Block\Order\Create\Form does not exist
```

But when I search this block in my App-Code, I don't have any block used with this name, anywhere in my custom modules.

I have only used the **Order\Create\Form** in one of my custom module in di.xml

di.xml code

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account">
    <plugin name="after_order_create_comment" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\GallerySchool" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

And calling in Custom\Module\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\GallerySchool

GallerySchool.php

```
<?php namespace SFC\School\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create;

class GallerySchool
{
    public function afterToHtml(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account $subject, $html)
    {
        $newBlockHtml = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('SFC_School::gallerylist.phtml')->toHtml();

        return $html.$newBlockHtml;
    }
}
```

But After removing both codes, still the issue remains the same. There is nothing in DB also with this block name. The same code is working fine with the Magento lower versions

Anyone, please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: may be you installed any extension through composer and that's using this block.. have you checked this?

Comment: Yes, I have searched in the complete project but nothing was found with this block used.